# huggingface evaluate function use multiple labels

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch, huggingface

i have two sentence that combine with encode_plus function and i want to done the NLI task with finetuning a BERT base model

i want a metric name for huggingface evaluator function to evaluate multiple labels

i used from this code

```py
metric = evaluate.combine(["accuracy", "f1", "precision", "recall"])
metrics = metric.compute(predictions=[0,1,1,2], references=[0,2,1,0])
```

and got this result

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 2
      1 metric = evaluate.combine(["accuracy", "f1", "precision", "recall"])
----> 2 metrics = metric.compute(predictions=[0,1,1,2], references=[0,2,1,0])
      4 metrics

File ~/anaconda3/envs/NER/lib/python3.10/site-packages/evaluate/module.py:862, in CombinedEvaluations.compute(self, predictions, references, **kwargs)
    860     batch = {"predictions": predictions, "references": references, **kwargs}
    861     batch = {input_name: batch[input_name] for input_name in evaluation_module._feature_names()}
--> 862     results.append(evaluation_module.compute(**batch))
    864 return self._merge_results(results)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/NER/lib/python3.10/site-packages/evaluate/module.py:444, in EvaluationModule.compute(self, predictions, references, **kwargs)
    442 inputs = {input_name: self.data[input_name] for input_name in self._feature_names()}
    443 with temp_seed(self.seed):
--> 444     output = self._compute(**inputs, **compute_kwargs)
    446 if self.buf_writer is not None:
    447     self.buf_writer = None

File ~/.cache/huggingface/modules/evaluate_modules/metrics/evaluate-metric--f1/0ca73f6cf92ef5a268320c697f7b940d1030f8471714bffdb6856c641b818974/f1.py:127, in F1._compute(self, predictions, references, labels, pos_label, average, sample_weight)
    126 def _compute(self, predictions, references, labels=None, pos_label=1, average="binary", sample_weight=None):
--> 127     score = f1_score(
    128         references, predictions, labels=labels, pos_label=pos_label, average=average, sample_weight=sample_weight
    129     )
...
   (...)
   1401         UserWarning,
   1402     )

ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].
```

Comment: The error seems to be telling you that you need to change the `average` setting to one of the provided options, so passing an extra keyword parameter of `average=` and then your choice in the `compute` call.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Thanks for your comment, i was use from ```average``` keyword in both functions but it was not any change in result